# Recursion ( return statement )

Tags: java, c++, recursion

I face a problem while solving a problem in codeforces using recursion in java .

```
package codeforces;
import java.util.Scanner;
public
class NewClass11 {
    static int solve(int x, int y, int count)
    {
        if (x > y) {

            return count;
        }
        else {
            count++;
            x = x * 3;
            y = y * 2;
            solve(x, y, count);
        }
        //here return statement required
    }
public
    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = ob.nextInt();
        int y = ob.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println(solve(x, y, count));
    }
}
```

Here IDE want to me a return statement at the last parenthesis of the solve method .But why this is not work like as c++ code? please suggest me another way.

But if I write code with c++ that works well.
here c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int solve(int x, int y, int count)
{
    if (x > y) {
        return count;
    }
    else {
        count++;
        x = x * 3;
        y = y * 2;
        solve(x, y, count);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    int count = 0;
    cout << solve(x, y, count);
}
```

Comment: `return solve(x,y,count)` in your recursive method. Java enforces this. C++ only partially enforces this at compile time, what you have in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Because when `if (x > y)` is false then the method doesn't return anything, and it needs to return an `int`.  It has nothing to do with recursion.  Every method in Java needs to return what it advertises it will return.

Comment: Your C++ code may compile, but it will give the wrong result because it has the same mistake as your Java code. It's just that C++ accepts it if you don't explicitly use `return` in your function that should return an `ìnt`, and then silently returns something invalid...

Comment: Wow, 17 column deep indentation :o

Comment: I fixed the formatting. To add a code block an easy way is to just type ``` a the line before and after the formatted code. Then you don't have to indent the code by an additional 4 spaces.

Comment: *But if I write code with c++ that works well.* - or so you have believe. Your C++ code invokes *undefined behavior* in `solve` when executing the path where condition `(x > y)` is false. That this *appears* to work in whatever configuration/toolchain you're using only fosters your misdirection. The code is *wrong*. Not all code paths taken in `solve` provide proper `return` results.

Comment: One of the worst behaviors of undefined behavior is when the code appears to work even though it is broken. It may appear to work for 30 days in a row then fail miserably  on the 31st with no changes in the code. My point is you have to understand the rules and learn not to break them.

Comment: hmm ,I understand .Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why this is not work like as c++ code?

Because C++ is different from Java.

The difference that applies in this case is that C++ doesn't require that all branches of a non-void function return. The shown C++ program is well-formed, so it compiles. Instead, if the function execution reaches the last curly brace without a return statement, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> code with c++ that works well

It doesn't "work well". The behaviour of the C++ program is undefined.

Any compiler worth using would warn about this potentially being the case. GCC, Clang and MSVC do warn about the shown program by default.

> please suggest me another way.

There is no "another way". Fix the program by adding the missing return statement, as suggested by your IDE.